# Why is the left derivative of this function not 2?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x-2 & \text{ for } x<3, \\\ 2x-4 & \text{ for } x\ge 3 \end{cases}$$
which of the following are true?

(I) $\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} = 2$

(II) $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} = 2$

(III) $f'(3)= 2$

I understand that the third statement is incorrect as when I drew the graph, this function was not continuous at $x=3$ therefore it's not differentiable. But to me, the first two statements are both correct. I took derivatives of this piecewise function and the derivatives
were $2$. But the correct answer is (II) only. So what's wrong with the first statement?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What is $f(3+h)$ when $h$ is negative?

Comment: What is the meaning of abbreviation "ap" in your title ?

Comment: @JeanMarie:  in U.S.A., one can take *Advanced Placement* exams to get college credit for high school courses such as calculus

Comment: You can't use derivative rules to compute the derivative at 3, because there is no single formula that defines $f(x)$ in a neighborhood of 3.  (You can use derivative rules at any other point, but not at 3.)  Have you tried evaluating the limits in parts I and II?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Thanks! It would have been normal that the OP answers me also. He/she must imagine that only stupid people ask such a question...

Comment: Note $f(3)=2\cdot 3-4 = 2$ but for $h< 0$ we hav $f(3+h) = 2\cdot (3+h) -2 = 4+2h$.  The left side limit (where all the values are strictly *less* than $3$) is not equal to $f(3)$ (where the value of $3$ is, naturally, *not* strictly less than $3$).

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry when I got my answer I left this site and this question behind and never came back to check on it until now. I didn’t see your ask in time. I wasn’t deliberately ignoring you or anything.

Comment: @DanVelleman Yeah, I see how this goes now. Thanks!

Comment: @fleablood Good point, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You thought you need to calculate the derivatives of $2x-2$ and $2x-4$ in both case, but this is not true. The point is that $f(3) =2(3)-4 = 2$, so when you calculate the limit in I, it's

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(3+h) - f(3)}{h} 
&= \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{2(3+h)-2 - 2}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{2h+2}{h}
\end{align}

and the limit does not exists (or tend to $-\infty$).

Another way to think about this: if both (I), (II) are correct, then
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{ f(3+h) - f(3)}{h}$$
exists and is $2$, so (III) must also be true. But you know that it false, so one of (I), (II) is false.

Answer (score 2):

Note: $3 \ge 3$ and $3 \not < 3$ so $f(3)=2\cdot 3-4 = 2$.

but for $h< 0$ then $3+h < 3$ and so $f(3+h) = 2\cdot (3+h) -2 = 4+2h$.

The left side limit (where all the values are strictly *less* than $3$) is not equal to $f(3)$ (where the value of $3$ is, naturally, *not* strictly less than $3$).

To play it out

$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac {f(x+ h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac {(4+2h) -(2)}h= \lim \frac {2h +2}h = \lim (2+\frac 2h) = -\infty$.

(Negative infinity as $h < 0$....)

...

To view it graphically, $f(3+h)\to 4$ while $f(3)=2$ the slope of the line gets steeper and steeper becoming infinitely steep.